# Настройка Ping через ICMP Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как разрешить пинг через протокол  ICMP  в Ubuntu?
Через TCP  все нормально пингует, а через ICMP пишет, что нет привилегий

пример кода:

```
$pong = net::ping->new("icmp");
(defined $pong) or die "Couldn't create Net::Ping object: $!\n":
if ($pong->ping("kingkong.com")) { print "The giant ape lives!\n"; }
else { print "All hail mighty Camera, friend of children!\n"; }
```

Comment: Какая версия ubuntu?

Comment: ping по сути своей является утилитой для обмена с указанным удаленным сервером ICMP сообщениями. То есть выполняя команду "ping 8.8.8.8" Вы посылаете серверу "8.8.8.8" ICMP Echo и (не)получаете ICMP Reply.
Скорее всего, Вы играли в пинг-понг именно ICMP запросами, сами того не подозревая. Если же нет, то прошу привести выполняемую команду.

Comment: Вот такой пример



     $pong = net::ping->new("icmp"); 
    (defined $pong) 
     or die "Couldn't create Net::Ping object: $!\n": 
     if ($pong->ping("kingkong.com")) { 
     print "The giant ape lives!\n"; 
     } else { 
     print "All hail mighty Camera, friend of children!\n"; 
     }

Comment: @Olga12, смотрите

    avp@avp-xub11:/etc/rsyslog.d$ ll /bin/ping
    -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 34740 Nov  8  2011 /bin/ping*
    avp@avp-xub11:/etc/rsyslog.d$ file /bin/ping

Видите бит **`s`** в правах и owner root?

ICMP реализуется через RAW socket, по умолчанию для этого нужны права root-а.

Попробуйте запустить свой скрипт из под sudo, думаю пойдет.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

ICMP реализуется через RAW socket, по умолчанию для этого нужны права root-а. Попробуйте запустить свой скрипт из под sudo, думаю пойдет.